# Justifying inline divs in CSS

Tags: css, html

Here's what I have in html:

```
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="box" id="box1"> </div>
    <div class="box" id="box2"> </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3"> </div>
</div>
```

And here's what I want to do with it:
[image]

Where the red arrows are all the same length **regardless of the width** of `row1` (or the 3 boxes even)

**Attempt**

Here's my css:

```
/* 1 row per line */
.row { 
       display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

/* and the box is inline */
.box {
       display: inline-block;
    text-align: justified;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The result:
[image]

Where the green arrows are of the same length

I've defined their widths temporarily as

```
#box1 { width: 50px; }
#box2 { width: 90px; }
#box3 { width: 50px; }
```

If I let w = row width,
the spacing should work for any w >= sum( width of the children boxes )

But according to firebug, the boxes doesn't even have a margin from `margin: 0 auto;`

I'll been tinkering with this for a while without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

Ultimately, I'll have a `<div class="window"></div>` containing an arbitrary number of rows where each row further contains an arbitrary number of boxes.

I define the width and height of each boxes, then the row and window dimensions adjust accordingly (which is the way block-level element behaves by default);

- The height of the row being equal to the greatest height of all its children boxes.
- The height of the window is then the sum of all the row heights
- The width of the window is the width of the row with the highest sum of the width of all its children boxes

The first 2 is automatic, but for the 3rd one, I can set it after I am done working with all of the rows.
Now the rest of the row will have its width filled up (`.row {width: 100%; }`). But then some of the rows may contain box(es) with the total width being less than that of the width of the window.

The end result would be something like so:
[image]
Where arrows (the spacing) of the same colour should have the same width.
(In the case of the second row in the picture, the spacing is simply 0. The width of the window (and all other rows) conform to its width)

A general approach is preferred.

---

**[Go to problem in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Ru2/4/)**

Comment: I don't have a quick answer for you, but I have to give you credit for an excellent question.

Comment: I was given the understanding that mark-ups should be based on what the content is, that's why I stopped using table for presentation purposes (semantic mismatch) :s

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for the problem?

Comment: is JavaScript okay for you, this can be achieved in jQuery easily & will be pixel perfect.

Comment: Hey, I did using javascript.. here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8jUdd/3/) (The last gap is not equal to other gaps because of `border` to the elements).

Comment: @Sylin I updated your fiddle. Here is the [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/c6Ru2/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are good with calculations (unlike me). You can use positioning. Something like this:

I am keeping a space of `2.5%` among the elements. You can also use fixed space instead .
Also, give some `min-width` to restrict more shrinking of the elements.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8jUdd/1/)**

## Update:

As the gap between the child elements is changing when the window is resized, you need to do calculations dynamically.

### javascript:

```
function setAlign(parentClass, childCommonClass) {
    var childDivs = document.getElementsByClassName(childCommonClass);
    var childDivsTotalWidth = 0;
    var childDivsLength = childDivs.length;
    var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName(parentClass)[0];
    var parentElementWidth = parentElement.offsetWidth;
    for (var i = 0; i < childDivsLength; i++) {
        childDivsTotalWidth += childDivs[i].offsetWidth;
    }
    var remainingWidth = parentElementWidth - childDivsTotalWidth;

    var gap = remainingWidth / (childDivsLength + 1);
    var leftWidth = gap;
    for (var j = 0; j < childDivsLength; j++) {
        if (j > 0) {
            leftWidth += gap + childDivs[j - 1].offsetWidth;
        }
        childDivs[j].style.left = leftWidth + "px";
    }
}

window.onload = setAlign('row', 'box');
window.onresize = function () {
    setAlign('row', 'box');
}
```

## [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/c6Ru2/12/)

Comment: @VenomVendor **This will work**.. you should do good calculations. (You are changing my calculations, do your own calculations if you change the width.). I just showed a example in the post. I even mentioned that one must be good with calculations. :)

Comment: @Sylin No, it is number of gap's between the child elements. ie. `childElements + 1`. In the fiddle, four gaps among the three child elements. I updated the fiddle again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by applying following css:

```
#wI-row1 { 
    width: 600px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#wI-row1:after{
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9L3Sk/)

**Edit**

As per your edit:

You should wrap all of your div with a div suppose ,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row" id="wI-row1">
    <div class="box" id="wI-Level">   </div>
    <div class="box" id="wI-Faction"> </div>
    <div class="box" id="wI-Gender">  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="wI-row2">
    <div class="box" id="wI-Level">   </div>
    <div class="box" id="wI-Faction"> </div>
    <div class="box" id="wI-Gender">  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> So, now don't set the width in #wI-row1, #wI-row2 as you have defined the width in .box, it would be okay. Just set the width of the .wrapper.

**Comment Response**

To make work text-align: justify the width has to given 100% with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: this is almost perfect! but there's no gap at the 2 ends, I am trying to play around with it atm, but I am not familiar with the technique being employed here.

Comment: You can give padding value like padding: 0 20px; in your #wI-row1

Comment: is there a way to work the automatic spacing into it as well?  right now I can shrink or expand the width of row 1 as desired and the spacing between the 3 boxes works great, but I cant use hard-coded padding for the 2 spaces at the end in that case because they would be fixed :(

Comment: It is automatically spacing both side but you have a fixed width defined in #wI-row1, so you need to consider what space you want, if you don't like in pixel you could apply in percentage too.

Comment: how does row:after affects how row behaves?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can achieve your goal by setting margin-left(?) to 50px, and row's last children margin-right:50px, and changing row class to text-align:left

maybe its better to use float instead of display-block

Comment: I've tried setting the margin manually, but then when the row width changes, I am back to the same problem again :(    I'll have to look into float

Comment: @Sylin check it is working.. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8jUdd/).

Comment: by floating you will have better support for browsers to, but for your problem you can just use percents, it's just a simple math problem!you cant try that too,instead of 50px maybe 8.3%

Comment: ok, I'll try to use float, but the main problem I have is that the equal spacing should be the _same length regardless of the width of_ the parent row :/   otherwise I am capable of the math

Comment: @C-Link It will not because everything is fixed in it.

Answer (score 1):

Mr_Green's answer is very good, especially since it accounts for resizing the window.

We can avoid absolute positioning by using marginLeft instead of left.  My approach uses percentages:

```
function justify(container) {
  var ch= container.children;
  var norm= container.offsetWidth/100;
  for(var chWidth=0, i=0 ; i < ch.length ; i++) {
    chWidth+= ch[i].offsetWidth/norm;
  }
  var Dpercent= (100-chWidth)/(ch.length+1);
  for(var i = 0 ; i < ch.length ; i++) {
    ch[i].style.marginLeft= Dpercent+'%';
  }
} //justify

window.onresize= window.onload= function() {
  justify(document.getElementById('row1'));
}
```

Comment: Oh hello again, Rick :)

I should note that just recently I've asked another question seeking the same effect and found a [css solution using flex box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055964/flex-justify-content-space-around-but-full-size-on-both-ends). The new question was geared towards tinkering with flex boxes in particular even when the 2 have the same goal, so I didn't quite know what to do with this question that I asked earlier in time.

Comment: That's cool.  I considered a flex box solution, but support seems to be limited or buggy:  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: Also, don't think I'm stalking you.  Your resize question was so interesting, I looked for other posts you had made.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had thought that supports for them should be well on their way by now, but I guess not. All this browser compat. business is a little vexing for my taste